# Convert multiple equations into function in R

Tags: r, function, equation

I have a series of 'snowballing' equations that each provide an output number, which then feeds into the next equation. I would like to efficiently turn all these building equations into one (if possible) function in R. My variables will be coming from columns from my dataframes. Provided is an example of the many equations. (This is for determining gas concentrations in a headspace sample).

```
    Hn2o=1/exp((A+(B/df$Temp)+C*log(df$Temp/K)+D*df$Temp)/R)
          A,B,C,D,K, and R are constants
    CgN2O=df$N2O_ppm
    Atm=df$Barometric_pressure
    PN2O=CgN2O*Atm
    AqN2O=Nw*((PN2O/Hn2o)*Mw)*10^3
          Nw and Mw are constants
```

Comment: What are your inputs and outputs?

Comment: Please "accept" one of the questions by clicking the checkmark next to the one you prefer.

Comment: The inputs are the column values: df$Temp, df$N2O_ppm, and df$Barometric_pressure. In this example, my desired output would be the AqN2O,which I would then use for another downstream equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. This allows you to feed in the dataset and the variable names and assuming your constants really are constants, it's fine to hardcode them.

```
funcName <- function(df, temp = "Temp", n20 = "N20_ppm", bp = "Barometric_pressure") {
    A <- 100
    B <- 100
    C <- 100
    D <- 100
    K <- 100
    R <- 100
    Nw <- 100
    Mw <- 100
    Hn2o <- 1 / exp((A + (B/df[[temp]]) + (C*log(df[[temp]]/K)) + (D*df[[temp]])) / R)
    AqN20 <- Nw * ((df[[n20]] * df[[bp]] / Hn2o) * Mw) * 10^3
    return(AqN20)
}

AqN20 <- funcName(df)
```

Alternative:

```
funcName <- function(df, temp = "Temp", n20 = "N20_ppm", bp = "Barometric_pressure", A = 100, B = 100, C = 100, D = 100, K = 100, R = 100, Nw = 100, Mw = 100) {
    Hn2o <- 1 / exp((A + (B/df[[temp]]) + (C*log(df[[temp]]/K)) + (D*df[[temp]])) / R)
    AqN20 <- Nw * ((df[[n20]] * df[[bp]] / Hn2o) * Mw) * 10^3
    return(AqN20)
}
```

Feed in alternative values with:

```
altA <- 110
altB <- 90
altR <- 150

AqN20 <- funcName(df, A = altA, B = altB, R = altR)
```

Comment: I tried to run this but when I call "AqN20" afterwards, I get an error message "Error: object 'AqN20' not found". Also, after I run this function, my assigned constants don't actually show up in the global environment viewer,  but the function does. Sorry for being a noob.

Comment: Yes, those values are internal to the function. You would need to assign the return value to a variable to have it show in the global environment... AqN20 <- funcName(df). Your constants are also internal, just add them as arguments in the function if you want to be able to set them globally and have the function read them in.

Comment: This worked and makes much more sense to me now! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read about writing functions, perhaps in [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html). This should be relatively straight-forward:

```
myfunc <- function(Temp, N20, Baro,
                   A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4, K = 5, R = 6,
                   Nw = 7, Mw = 8) {
  Hn2o <- 1 / exp((A+(B/Temp)+C*log(Temp/K)+D*Temp)/R)
  PN29 <- N20 * Baro
  Nw * ( (PN20 / Hn2o)*Mw ) * 10^3
}
```

Whether you put the "constant" variables in the function formals as I've done here, or as simple variables within the function, is mostly a personal thing.

```
myfunc <- function(Temp, N20, Baro) {
  A = 1; B = 2; C = 3; D = 4; K = 5; R = 6
  Nw = 7; Mw = 8
  Hn2o <- 1 / exp((A+(B/Temp)+C*log(Temp/K)+D*Temp)/R)
  PN29 <- N20 * Baro
  Nw * ( (PN20 / Hn2o)*Mw ) * 10^3
}
```

(I put all constants on single lines merely for direct comparison with the other function, not that it imposes any performance improvement.)

Instead of feeding it dataframes, I'm dealing with things as direct vectors. That way, if you have a data.frame, you can just feed in columns:

```
df <- data.frame(temperature = 1, n20_ppm = 2, barometric = 3)
results <- myfunc(df$temperature, df$n20_ppm, df$barometric)
```

Comment: I perused the web for a few hours but couldn't wrap my head around the functions for some reason. Might've been the hours before spent on learning the dplyr package. Thanks!